# Composer disable class map

Tags: php, composer-php

I had installed phpunit in my project, I decided to dump the loader just to see what is in it

```
[classMap:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => Array
    (
        [File_Iterator] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator/src/Iterator.php
        [File_Iterator_Facade] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator/src/Facade.php
        [File_Iterator_Factory] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator/src/Factory.php
        [PHPUnit_Exception] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Exception.php
        [PHPUnit_Extensions_GroupTestSuite] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Extensions/GroupTestSuite.php
        [PHPUnit_Extensions_PhptTestCase] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Extensions/PhptTestCase.php
        [PHPUnit_Extensions_PhptTestSuite] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Extensions/PhptTestSuite.php
        [PHPUnit_Extensions_RepeatedTest] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Extensions/RepeatedTest.php
        [PHPUnit_Extensions_TestDecorator] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Extensions/TestDecorator.php
        [PHPUnit_Extensions_TicketListener] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Extensions/TicketListener.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Assert] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Assert.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/AssertionFailedError.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_BaseTestListener] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/BaseTestListener.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_CodeCoverageException] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/CodeCoverageException.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_And] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/And.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_ArrayHasKey] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/ArrayHasKey.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_ArraySubset] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/ArraySubset.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_Attribute] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/Attribute.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_Callback] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/Callback.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_ClassHasAttribute] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/ClassHasAttribute.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_ClassHasStaticAttribute] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/ClassHasStaticAttribute.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_Composite] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/Composite.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_Count] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/Count.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_Exception] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/Exception.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_ExceptionCode] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/ExceptionCode.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_ExceptionMessage] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/ExceptionMessage.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_ExceptionMessageRegExp] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/ExceptionMessageRegExp.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_FileExists] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/FileExists.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_GreaterThan] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/GreaterThan.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsAnything] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/IsAnything.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsEmpty] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/IsEmpty.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsEqual] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/IsEqual.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsFalse] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/IsFalse.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsIdentical] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/IsIdentical.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsInstanceOf] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/IsInstanceOf.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsJson] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/IsJson.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsNull] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/IsNull.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsTrue] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/IsTrue.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsType] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/IsType.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_JsonMatches] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/JsonMatches.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_JsonMatches_ErrorMessageProvider] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/JsonMatches/ErrorMessageProvider.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_LessThan] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/LessThan.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_Not] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/Not.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_ObjectHasAttribute] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/ObjectHasAttribute.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_Or] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/Or.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_PCREMatch] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/PCREMatch.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_SameSize] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/SameSize.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_StringContains] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/StringContains.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_StringEndsWith] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/StringEndsWith.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_StringMatches] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/StringMatches.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_StringStartsWith] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/StringStartsWith.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_TraversableContains] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/TraversableContains.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_TraversableContainsOnly] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/TraversableContainsOnly.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_Xor] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/Xor.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Error] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Error.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Deprecated] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Error/Deprecated.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Notice] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Error/Notice.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Error/Warning.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Exception] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Exception.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_ExceptionWrapper] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/ExceptionWrapper.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/ExpectationFailedException.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_IncompleteTest] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/IncompleteTest.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_IncompleteTestCase] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/IncompleteTestCase.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_IncompleteTestError] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/IncompleteTestError.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_InvalidCoversTargetError] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/InvalidCoversTargetError.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_InvalidCoversTargetException] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/InvalidCoversTargetException.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_BadMethodCallException] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Exception/BadMethodCallException.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_Identity] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Builder/Identity.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_InvocationMocker] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Builder/InvocationMocker.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_Match] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Builder/Match.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_MethodNameMatch] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Builder/MethodNameMatch.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_Namespace] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Builder/Namespace.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_ParametersMatch] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Builder/ParametersMatch.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_Stub] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Builder/Stub.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Exception] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Exception/Exception.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Generator] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Invocation] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Invocation.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_InvocationMocker] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/InvocationMocker.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Invocation_Object] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Invocation/Object.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Invocation_Static] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Invocation/Static.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Invokable] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Invokable.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Matcher.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_AnyInvokedCount] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Matcher/AnyInvokedCount.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_AnyParameters] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Matcher/AnyParameters.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_ConsecutiveParameters] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Matcher/ConsecutiveParameters.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_Invocation] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Matcher/Invocation.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_InvokedAtIndex] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Matcher/InvokedAtIndex.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_InvokedAtLeastCount] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Matcher/InvokedAtLeastCount.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_InvokedAtLeastOnce] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Matcher/InvokedAtLeastOnce.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_InvokedAtMostCount] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Matcher/InvokedAtMostCount.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_InvokedCount] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Matcher/InvokedCount.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_InvokedRecorder] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Matcher/InvokedRecorder.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_MethodName] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Matcher/MethodName.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_Parameters] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Matcher/Parameters.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_StatelessInvocation] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Matcher/StatelessInvocation.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockBuilder] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/MockBuilder.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/MockObject.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_RuntimeException] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Exception/RuntimeException.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Stub] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Stub.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Stub_ConsecutiveCalls] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Stub/ConsecutiveCalls.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Stub_Exception] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Stub/Exception.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Stub_MatcherCollection] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Stub/MatcherCollection.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Stub_Return] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Stub/Return.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Stub_ReturnArgument] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Stub/ReturnArgument.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Stub_ReturnCallback] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Stub/ReturnCallback.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Stub_ReturnSelf] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Stub/ReturnSelf.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Stub_ReturnValueMap] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Stub/ReturnValueMap.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Verifiable] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Verifiable.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_OutputError] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/OutputError.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_RiskyTest] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/RiskyTest.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_RiskyTestError] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/RiskyTestError.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_SelfDescribing] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/SelfDescribing.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_SkippedTest] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/SkippedTest.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_SkippedTestCase] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/SkippedTestCase.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_SkippedTestError] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/SkippedTestError.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_SkippedTestSuiteError] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/SkippedTestSuiteError.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_SyntheticError] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/SyntheticError.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Test] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Test.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_TestFailure] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestFailure.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestListener.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite_DataProvider] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite/DataProvider.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_UnintentionallyCoveredCodeError] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/UnintentionallyCoveredCodeError.php
        [PHPUnit_Framework_Warning] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Warning.php
        [PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php
        [PHPUnit_Runner_Exception] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/Exception.php
        [PHPUnit_Runner_Filter_Factory] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/Filter/Factory.php
        [PHPUnit_Runner_Filter_GroupFilterIterator] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/Filter/Group.php
        [PHPUnit_Runner_Filter_Group_Exclude] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/Filter/Group/Exclude.php
        [PHPUnit_Runner_Filter_Group_Include] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/Filter/Group/Include.php
        [PHPUnit_Runner_Filter_Test] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/Filter/Test.php
        [PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php
        [PHPUnit_Runner_TestSuiteLoader] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/TestSuiteLoader.php
        [PHPUnit_Runner_Version] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/Version.php
        [PHPUnit_TextUI_Command] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php
        [PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php
        [PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_Blacklist] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Blacklist.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_Configuration] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Configuration.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_ErrorHandler] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/ErrorHandler.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Fileloader.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_Filesystem] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Filesystem.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_Filter] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Filter.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_Getopt] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Getopt.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_GlobalState] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/GlobalState.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_InvalidArgumentHelper] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/InvalidArgumentHelper.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_Log_JSON] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Log/JSON.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_Log_JUnit] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Log/JUnit.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_Log_TAP] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Log/TAP.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_PHP] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_PHP_Default] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/Default.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_PHP_Windows] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/Windows.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_Printer] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Printer.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_Regex] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Regex.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_String] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/String.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_Test] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Test.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_TestDox_NamePrettifier] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/TestDox/NamePrettifier.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_TestDox_ResultPrinter] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/TestDox/ResultPrinter.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_TestDox_ResultPrinter_HTML] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/TestDox/ResultPrinter/HTML.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_TestDox_ResultPrinter_Text] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/TestDox/ResultPrinter/Text.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_TestSuiteIterator] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/TestSuiteIterator.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_Type] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Type.php
        [PHPUnit_Util_XML] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/XML.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Driver] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Driver.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Driver_HHVM] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Driver/HHVM.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Driver_PHPDBG] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Driver/PHPDBG.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Driver_Xdebug] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Driver/Xdebug.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Exception] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Exception.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Exception_UnintentionallyCoveredCode] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Exception/UnintentionallyCoveredCode.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Filter.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_Clover] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/Clover.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_Crap4j] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/Crap4j.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_Factory] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/Factory.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_HTML] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/HTML.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_HTML_Renderer] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/HTML/Renderer.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_HTML_Renderer_Dashboard] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/HTML/Renderer/Dashboard.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_HTML_Renderer_Directory] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/HTML/Renderer/Directory.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_HTML_Renderer_File] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/HTML/Renderer/File.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_Node] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/Node.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_Node_Directory] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/Node/Directory.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_Node_File] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/Node/File.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_Node_Iterator] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/Node/Iterator.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_PHP] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/PHP.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_Text] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/Text.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_XML] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/XML.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_XML_Directory] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/XML/Directory.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_XML_File] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/XML/File.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_XML_File_Coverage] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/XML/File/Coverage.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_XML_File_Method] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/XML/File/Method.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_XML_File_Report] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/XML/File/Report.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_XML_File_Unit] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/XML/File/Unit.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_XML_Node] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/XML/Node.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_XML_Project] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/XML/Project.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_XML_Tests] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/XML/Tests.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_XML_Totals] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/XML/Totals.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Util] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Util.php
        [PHP_CodeCoverage_Util_InvalidArgumentHelper] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Util/InvalidArgumentHelper.php
        [PHP_Timer] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-timer/src/Timer.php
        [PHP_Token] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_TokenWithScope] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_TokenWithScopeAndVisibility] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_Token_ABSTRACT] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_Token_AMPERSAND] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_Token_AND_EQUAL] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_Token_ARRAY] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_Token_ARRAY_CAST] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_Token_AS] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_Token_ASYNC] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_Token_AT] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_Token_AWAIT] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_Token_BACKTICK] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_Token_BAD_CHARACTER] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_Token_BOOLEAN_AND] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_Token_BOOLEAN_OR] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_Token_BOOL_CAST] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_Token_BREAK] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_Token_CALLABLE] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_Token_CARET] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_Token_CASE] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_Token_CATCH] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        [PHP_Token_CHARACTER] => /var/wwwdev/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token.php
        ...
```

And this is just half of it, it wouldn't even let me post it all on here. IMHO this is unacceptable, furthermore I removed the package using

```
composer remove phpunit/phpunit --update-with-dependencies
```

Then ran

```
composer dump-autoload
composer update
```

The class map is still present.

Is there any way I can explicitly tell composer **not** to use this method of loading and any packages that still use it?

Comment: Isn't this the point of composer? To include your set dependencies into one `autoload.php` file that you can include in your application?

Comment: @Jamesking56 maybe, but I would deffinitely **not want** this amount of information to be processed on each request of my application. There are better ways to load classes.

Comment: If you don't want phpunit to be required in production, you can install it into your development dependencies by using `composer require phpunit/phpunit --dev`. This way PHPUnit will only be installed in development.

Comment: Then when installing your application into your live environment, you can run `composer install --no-dev`

Comment: @Jamesking56 this question is not regarding phpunit but the method of loading. Who knows maybe tomorrow there will be another package installed with triple this number of classes, then what?

Comment: @Jamesking56 so that would disable class map autoloading?

Comment: As I said, if its a package that you don't want in production, you can tell composer that its a package only for development. This way composer will only install that dependency when you are in development and not on your live setup.

Comment: Other than that, include dependencies manually without composer if you prefer.

Comment: As far as computer resources go, this is pretty irrelevant. It takes longer to establish a database connection than to parse this array or look up a value in it... "Unacceptable" is quite a strong word to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell Composer to install packages from `dist` if you prefer:

`composer require <vendor>/<package> --prefer-dist`

As a best practice, I would segregate your application's **development-only** packages vs. packages you use in production by installing development packages using:

`composer require <vendor>/<package> --dev`

and then in production, running this command when installing your application:

`composer install --no-dev`

Furthermore, you could combine these in production like so:

`composer install --no-dev --prefer-dist`

Lastly, if you are using continuous deployment (automated deployment) you can also tell composer that you cannot interact with it (stopping any questions from composer):

`composer install --no-dev --prefer-dist --no-interaction`

You can also optimise the autoloader in production by running:

`composer dump-autoload --optimize`

Comment: Excuse me, this might be a silly question, but what exactly is `dist`?

Comment: If your Composer is configured to download from `source`, it will clone each package's repository to the vendor folder. If it is configured to `dist`, it will download a release ZIP file instead.